# SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'univ' cannot be null

Tags: mysql, laravel

I am trying to insert data in table using laravel and mysql but I see the error `SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'univ' cannot be null` , while I am not inserting any null value. I am filling all the field in form. what is the reason? please help.

My form is education.blade.php and its code is given.

```
@section('content')

    <div class="container"><br>
        <h1 class="text-success text-center">Add Education Here</h1><br>
        <div class="col-md-offset-3 col-md-6 m-auto d-block">
            <form action="edu" method="post">
                <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{csrf_token()}}">
                <input type="text" name="degree" value=" MSc / BS" disabled>
                <div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>University: </label>
                        <input type="text" name="univ" id="" class="form-control">
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Country: </label>
                        <input type="text" name="country" id="" class="form-control">
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Year: </label>
                        <input type="number" name="year" id="" class="form-control">
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Research Area: </label>
                        <input type="text" name="research" id="" class="form-control">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <input type="submit" name="submit" value="ADD!" class="btn btn-lg col-md-offset-3 col-md-6 m-auto d-block">
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>

@endsection
```

**The code of my migration  is given here.**

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreateEducsTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('educs', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned();
            $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('registrations');
            $table->string('degree');
            $table->string('univ');
            $table->string('country');
            $table->integer('year');
            $table->text('research_area');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('educs');
    }
}
```

**The code of my controller is given EduContoller.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Request;

use App\educ;

class EduController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for creating a new resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function create()
    {
        //
        return view('education');
    }

    /**
     * Store a newly created resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        //
        educ::create(Request::all());
        return 'inserted';
    }

    /**
     * Display the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function show($id)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for editing the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function edit($id)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Update the specified resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function update(Request $request, $id)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Remove the specified resource from storage.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function destroy($id)
    {
        //
    }
}
```

**and The code of my model is given here.**

```
    <?php

    namespace App;

    use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

    class educ extends Model
    {
        //
        protected $fillable = ['user_id','degree','univ','country','year','research_area'];
    }
```

and the error which i am getting while submitting the form is given.

Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'univ' cannot be null

Comment: stop making univ being 'null'

Comment: I am inserting value in univ column and it is not null in database, but same error

Comment: in store function firstly print this `dd($request->all())`. Check if value print.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem lies in the univ column being null. When you wrote the initial migration for that table you didn't add the `->nullable()` column modifier. So the SQL that creates the table, which is generated by the ORM, does not have the `NULL` modifier you'd expect. Two options here depending on your acceptance criteria:
1. Add the nullable modifier with a migration
2. Make sure you submit univ every time you post, and thus make it a required field on the frontend for a good UX.

That list isn't exhaustive, but it'll get you going. Hope all goes well!

Answer (score 1):

You need to make the univ column nullable as m.a.solano93 said.
Easiest way to do this is below.

```
php artisan make:migration update_educs_table
```

In the migrations `up` method

```
Schema::table('educs', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->string('univ')->nullable()->change();
});
```

Then run your migration

```
php artisan migrate
```

Answer (score -2):

Im not sure what exactly what `educ::create(Request::all());` does, but could you try and change that line with the lines below and tell us do you still get the same error. **Also a note, you still need to add some text to `univ` even when you are not sending it, because if you are not sending it, it is treated as `null`**

```
$education = new educ($request->all());
$education->save();
```

Comment: Illuminate\Support\Facades\Request::all()

Comment: my table name in database is educs by using above statements I got the error now is Symfony \ Component \ Debug \ Exception \ FatalThrowableError (E_ERROR)
Call to undefined method Illuminate\Support\Facades\Request::all()

Comment: What laravel version are you using?

Comment: laravel  version 5.7.8

Comment: You should use `$request->all()` instead of `Request::all()`